How to forward one email to two SMTP server using postfix?
My Requirements
I have two email servers, james and winmail. They hold same users, for example, account 1@example.com exists both in james and winmail.
When someone sends a email to 1@example.com, I expect that both james and winmail receive that email, and the eml content should be exactly the same.
My Attempts
I tried to configure two MX in DNS. But it can only map example.com to james or winmail, not both.
Then I try postfix, which means example.com resolved to postfix server, and when postfix receives the email, it should forward this email to james and winmail without saving it to local storage.
However, /etc/postfix/transport only supports map example.com to one server too.
So how can I make postfix forward every email to these two SMTP servers at the same time?

What are you trying to achieve here beyond sending the same email to 2 different servers? An archive of messages? High availability? Something else? (Please update your question rather than replying in comments - your answer should be too big to fit in the available space)
